# Using GroupByKey with having each key in its own window

Tags: apache-beam

I have an unbounded source of data (Kafka stream) as the input for my beam job.

The characteristic of data:

1. They are groups of element (group size is between 5-20 elements).
2. The key of each group is an unique identifier and only used for that group.
3. The maximum time difference between the first element and last element in a group is less than 2 seconds.

[image]

What I want to perform is:

1. Grouping them together by their key
2. Processing each group individually.

I figured out that I can use GroupByKey function to achieve this.

[image]

But then , since it is an unbounded source, I need to apply windowing otherwise the GroupBy will never finish.

The problem is that, I can't find a windowing function that allows me to do it without chopping data.

[image]

My question: Is there a way that can allow me to group each key in its own window, and close it after a certain amount of time? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably try to use `Session` windows where every session will correspond to the group in your input dataset.